# Extracting elements from a struct stored in an std::container

Tags: c++, struct, std

I have a std::vector which stores a complex struct S (coming from a real time source) which consists of nested structs N1, N2, N3. The struct S has a time field.

A common task, is to retrieve any of the 3 nested structs between two times, for example getSequenceN1(startTime, stopTime, itrStart, itrStop), which gives 2 iterators to the start and end of the subsequence.

So the code would look something like this:

```
struct {
   double time
   struct N1;
   struct N2;
   struct N3;
} S;

class D {


public: 
   void getSequenceN1(startTime, stopTime, itrStart, itrStop);
   void getSequenceN2(startTime, stopTime, itrStart, itrStop);
   void getSequenceN3(startTime, stopTime, itrStart, itrStop);

private: 
  std::vector<S> stream;
};
```

What would the right way of implementing the functionality of **getSequenceN1**?

One way would of course be to have a vector for each N1, N2, N3, (in real live there are more than 3 subtracts) but i am wondering if std offers some nice feature for this?

I am not forced to use a vector btw, any std container (maybe even boost) works. I was hoping I could provide something like a **view** for the vector where we either only see N1 N2 or N3.

One way would be to provide customized Iterators which give back N1 N2 and N3 respectively.

Comment: What's actually wrong with `std::vector<S>`? Looks fine for me.

Comment: Yes but the user is not interested in S, he is interested in either N1, N2 or N3

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `S` is not a type, it is an object.

Comment: @user695652 Your code is incorrect (see comment above.) Please post real code.

Comment: Ah, I see now. You could extract particular sequences `std::vector<N1>` using an appropriate and return this one.

Comment: @  juanchopanza this is a design question

Comment: What is `getSequenceN1()` supposed to do?

Comment: @ Alan Stokes it should return a subsequence of N1s between two time stamps

Comment: Why do you omit the return and parameter types? Design is easier given an accurate and precise specification.

Comment: @ Alan Stokes I was thinking to return the interval using two iterators, I added void now

Comment: @user695652 Doesn't answer your question, but if this is supposed to return iterators denoting the start and stop values, then this would be a more appropriate prototype:  `std::pair<iter1, iter2> getSequenceN1(startTime, stopTime);`  i.e. return a pair of iterators denoting the start and stop values.

Comment: @user695652 `I have a std::vector which stores a complex struct S (coming from a real time source)`  Maybe the issue should be dealt with at the source.  Is there a reason to keep around this struct?  If there isn't a reason, maybe build a `std::vector<std::map<double, Nvalue>>`, where the map has the time as a key, and the N value as the data?  The vector just denotes whether it is N1, N2, N3, etc.  Then to retrieve the data for say, N3 between times t1 and t2 -- `vector[2].find(t1), vector[2].find(t3)`  would be returned to the user.  Or I could be all wet...

Answer (score 1):

```
void getSequenceN1(double startTime, 
                   double stopTime, 
                   vector<struct N1>& sequence)
{
    
    for( S cur: stream)
    {
        if (s.time >= startTime && s.time < endTime)
        {
             sequence.push-back(s.N1's_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Optimize and adjust start and end conditions to suit. For example, if S is not going to be modified while you are examining the sequence, you can use a vector of pointers to struct N1 and save a some copying.

## EDIT

Playing around with the concept. Still need to abstract it because declaring a different iterator for each sub structure is a pretty stupid solution. Suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

struct N1
{
    int count;
    bool operator==(const N1 & rhs) const
    {
        return count == rhs.count;
    }
    bool operator!=(const N1 & rhs) const
    {
        return count != rhs.count;
    }
};

struct S
{
    double time;
    struct N1 n1;
    bool operator<(const S & rhs) const
    {
        return time < rhs.time;
    }
};

class N1Iterator: public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, struct N1>
{
    std::vector<S>::iterator mIt;
public:
    N1Iterator()
    {

    }
    N1Iterator(std::vector<S>::iterator it) :
            mIt(it)
    {

    }
    N1Iterator(const N1Iterator& it) :
            mIt(it.mIt)
    {

    }
    N1Iterator& operator++()
    {
        ++mIt;
        return *this;
    }
    N1Iterator operator++(int)
    {
        N1Iterator tmp(*this);
        operator++();
        return tmp;
    }
    bool operator==(const N1Iterator& rhs)
    {
        return mIt->n1 == rhs.mIt->n1;
    }
    bool operator!=(const N1Iterator& rhs)
    {
        return mIt->n1 != rhs.mIt->n1;
    }
    N1& operator*()
    {
        return mIt->n1;
    }
    N1* operator->()
    {
        return &mIt->n1;
    }
};

std::vector<S> stream;

N1Iterator & getSequenceN1(double startTime,
                         double stopTime,
                         N1Iterator & begin,
                         N1Iterator & end)
{
    S key;
    key.time = startTime;
    begin=N1Iterator(std::lower_bound(stream.begin(), stream.end(), key));
    key.time = stopTime;
    end=N1Iterator(std::lower_bound(stream.begin(), stream.end(), key));

    return begin;
}

int main(int argc, char **argsv)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
    {
        S s1;
        s1.time = count;
        s1.n1.count = count;
        stream.push_back(s1);
    }
    N1Iterator begin;
    N1Iterator end;

    getSequenceN1(3, 7, begin, end);

    while (begin != end)
    {
        std::cout << begin->count << std::endl;
        ++begin;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I was looking for something in sublinear time, i.e., not traversing the elements.

Comment: Assuming S is ordered by time, you can speed up finding the start with a binary search and stop after you hit endTime, but to extract the N1s, I think you're stuck.